# query to see class attribute

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Is there a SQL syntax to see the value of an class attribute using WebUI of OrientDB ?

I can use the following to edit the value : `ALTER CLASS Employee CUSTOM minAge=16` ([doc](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.1.x/SQL-Alter-Class.html))
But I can't find a way to check out the value set.

I can do that using Java API : `graph.getVertexType("Employee").getCustom("minAge")`
I need this as a SQL query.

my orientdb version : 2.1.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT FROM (
   SELECT expand(classes) from metadata:schema
) WHERE name = 'theClassName'
```

OrientDB v 2.1.x is not supported anymore, I strongly suggest you to upgrade to v 3.0

Comment: Works like a charm thanks. We are considering upgrading with great interest indeed ;)